# Show or hide div elements from AspNetCore

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I working with InstagramApiSharp and when user LogIn sometimes it is required to send a code to phone or email.
So I have

```
<div id="login">
```

where you enter login and password
If app needs to send code this div must hide and show

```
<div id="сheck">
```

So, how and where can I interact with HTML from C#?

This is project

[image: project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action you can set `ViewBag.IsLoginVisible = true;`

Then in your HTML (.cshtml) file following statement:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsLoginVisible != null && ViewBag.IsLoginVisible == true)
{
    <div id="login">
        <!-- Your code -->
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div id="check">
        <!-- Your code -->
    </div>
}
```